# How do I get values by rows in a data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a large data frame with multiple columns and rows, and I would like to retrieve all values in each row, excluding the first column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 2, 4, 7], ['B', 6, 1, 5], ['C', 4, 2, 2], ['D', 3, 9, 8]], columns = ["Pen", "A", 'B', 'C'])
    
values = []
for row in df.iterrows(0, 1):
    values. Append(values)

print(values)>
```

expected:

[2, 4, 7, 6, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 9, 8]

My code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use stack():

```
vals=list(df.iloc[:,1:].stack())
#[2, 4, 7, 6, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to select only the numeric columns then [**`pandas.DataFrame.stack`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [**`pandas.Series.tolist`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) to make a list of every number found :

```
import numpy as np

out= df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).stack().to_list()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

[2, 4, 7, 6, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 9, 8]
```

Comment: this code work out!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list, get rid of the `Pen` column and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then convert the Series [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
l = df.set_index('Pen').stack().tolist()
```

Output: `[2, 4, 7, 6, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 9, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
out = df.iloc[:,1:].to_numpy().ravel().tolist()
#[2, 4, 7, 6, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 9, 8]
```